# Change in route param doesn't updates the view in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

So I have this configuration for my single page app:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ng', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
      when('/product/id/:id', {
         template: '<product-details></product-details>'
      })
});

app.directive('productDetails', function() {
   return {
      controller: 'productDetailsController',
      templateUrl: 'templates/product_details.html'
   }
});

app.controller('productDetailsController', function($scope, product) {
   $scope.product = product;
})

app.factory('product', function($http, $routeParams) {
   var product = {};
   var id = encodeURIComponent($routeParams.id);

   $http.
      get('/api/v1/product/id/' + id).
      success(function(data) {
         return product.data = data;
      });

   return product;
})
```

When I move from localhost:3000/#/product/**id/id_1** to localhost:300/#/product/**id/id_2** it doesn't update the view with the contents of the product with id as id_2 until I refresh the browser. Also, if the last visited url was of, say id_1, and I'm currently on id_2 then when I click the back button the url changes to id_1 but the view continues to be of id_2. I googled but found solutions to similar problems in React and Vue but not in Angular. How can I make the route to reload the view when the route parameter changes?

Comment: Probably you should post controller code as well...

Comment: @Developer I did it now. Hope this would help. :(

Comment: Can u make a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem gets resolved upon moving the product service code directly to the controller instead of creating a product service of its own using app.factory() and then injecting it to the controller.

I am not very sure but I reckon the service code (product service in this case) are executed only once by angular (at the time of dependency injection). But the code in controller block is executed again even on a change in the routeParameters.